# Python: Jupyter Notebook Create Dynamic Checklist User Input that Runs Code

Tags: python, forms, list, user-interface

I'm using Python Jupyter Notebook with Python version 3.5

I want to create an user input form that is a checklist inside the Jupyter notebook.  Please see the image for what I roughly want the checklist to look like.

If a user checks a box, I want to write code that states for example:

a) If box is checked, run this script
b) If these 3 boxes are checked, run these 3 scripts

## any help on this is greatly appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 4):

ipywidgets (https://minrk-ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) is what you are looking for.
Here is the skeleton for your program [EDIT, typo err]

```
import ipywidgets as widgets

cb1 = widgets.Checkbox(description="cb1")
cb2 = widgets.Checkbox(description="cb2")
cb3 = widgets.Checkbox(description="cb3")
cb4 = widgets.Checkbox(description="cb4")

pb = widgets.Button(
    description='Click me',
    disabled=False,
    button_style='', # 'success', 'info', 'warning', 'danger' or ''
    tooltip='Click me',
)

def on_button_clicked(b):
    print("clicked on:",b)
    print("cb1:", cb1.value)
    print("cb2:", cb2.value)
    print("cb3:", cb3.value)
    print("cb4:", cb4.value)

pb.on_click(on_button_clicked)

ui = widgets.VBox([widgets.HBox([cb1, cb2]), widgets.HBox([cb3, cb4]),pb])

display(ui)
```

Comment: Have you figured out why must the descriptions be reset?

Comment: No, but there is a more elegant solution : `cb1 = widgets.Checkbox()
cb2 = widgets.Checkbox()
cb3 = widgets.Checkbox()
cb4 = widgets.Checkbox()

cb1.description="cb1"
cb2.description="cb2"
cb3.description="cb3"
cb4.description="cb4"`

Comment: typo when creating the Checkbox instances (despcription). maybe this is why you have to reset the description attribute